# ¿Como puedo ordenar una matriz de forma descendente en python?

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

Qué tal amigos, yo de nuevo.
Estoy a punto de terminar un código, de ingreso de productos con nombre y precio.
Me piden ordenar de forma descendente por precio los productos.

Si bien agrego la opción para revertir los datos, sigue sin funcionarme.

El codigo es este

```
import numpy as np


matriz_productos = np.empty((0,2), int)
def main():
    opcion = 0
    while (opcion != 4):
        print("<<< Bienvenido/a Gestion System >>>")
        print("¡¿Qué desea hacer?!")
        print("(1) - Registrar Producto Nuevo")
        print("(2) - Ordenar Productos")
        print("(3) - Clasificar Productos")
        print("(4) - Salir")
        opcion = int(input())

        if opcion == 1:
            registrar()
        if opcion == 2:
            ordenar()
        if opcion == 3:
            clasificar()
        if opcion == 4:
            print("<<< Ha salido del sistema exitosamente, gracias por usar Gestion System >>>")

    ############################################
    # # # Funcion de Registro de Productos # # #
    ############################################

def registrar():
    global matriz_productos
    try:
        print("<<< Registro de Producto Nuevo >>>")
        print("- Ingrese nombre del producto")
        nombre_producto = input()
        print("- Ingrese precio del producto")
        precio_producto = int(input())
        matriz_productos = np.append(matriz_productos, [[nombre_producto,precio_producto]], axis=0)
        print("<<< Producto registrado correctamente >>>")
        for arr_productos in matriz_productos:
            print("*****************************")
            print("Nombre:", arr_productos[0])
            print("Precio:","$", arr_productos[1],"\n")
            print("*****************************")
    except:
        print("!!! ERROR: Por favor Ingrese un formato de precio sin puntos !!!")

    ############################################
    # # # Funcion de Ordenado de Productos # # #  ######## AQUI ESTA LO DE ORDENAR.
    ############################################
def ordenar():
        print("Seleccione en que orden quiere ordenar:")
        print("(1) - Ordenar de forma descendente")   
        op_ordenar = int(input())
        
        global matriz_productos
        if(op_ordenar == 1):
            ordenado = np.argsort(matriz_productos[::,1])
            desc = ordenado[::-1]
            matriz_ordenada = matriz_productos[desc]
            for arr_productos in matriz_ordenada:
                print("*****************************")
                print("Nombre:", arr_productos[0])
                print("Precio:","$", arr_productos[1],"\n")
                print("*****************************")
```

El formato de salida cuando trato de ordenarlo es el siguiente:

[image: Parece ser algo simple]

¿Qué puede estar pasando? el parlante de baño no debería ir abajo del BT? parece ser algún detalle, que quizás yo no vea.
De antemano agradezco a la persona que quiera ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

De la siguiente forma se puede conseguir:

Primero, definimos el tipo de datos estructurado `dt` e iniciamos `matriz_productos` como un array vacío de este tipo:

```py
import numpy as np

dt = [("nombre", np.object), ("precio", np.int32)]
matriz_productos = np.empty((0, 2), dtype=dt)
```

`dt` nos sirve para almacenar objectos de Python (en nuestro caso, concretamente, strings de cualquier longitud) y números enteros de 32 bits.

A continuación, modificamos la función `registrar` de esta forma:

```py
def registrar():
    global matriz_productos, dt

    try:
        # ...

        matriz_productos = np.append(
            matriz_productos,
            np.array([(nombre_producto, precio_producto)], dtype=dt)
        )

    # ...
```

Finalmente, modificamos la función `ordenar` de esta forma:

```py
def ordenar():
    # ...

    global matriz_productos

    if(op_ordenar == 1):
        matriz_ordenada = np.sort(matriz_productos, order=["precio"], axis=0)[::-1]

        # ...
```

`matriz_ordenada` es una copia de `matriz_productos` ordenada **descendentemente** por el campo ***precio***.

`[::-1]` hace que el orden sea **descendente**. Si quitamos esta parte, el orden es **ascendente**.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado. Aún así el ejercicio me pide hacerlo bajo numpy. Sin embargo excelente aporte para practicar me sirve. Se agradece

Comment: De acuerdo. Acabo de encontrar una forma sólo con arrays de Numpy y he editado mi respuesta. Mira por favor si ahora te sirve y me dices.